# get notification Intent from Activity

Tags: android, notifications

CODE:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;


Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
notifyIntent.putExtra("notification", "notificationIntentBlahHello");

notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelID);

    notificationBuilder
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_post)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000})
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 1,1)
            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent);


    notificationManager.notify("do_not1", (int) (Math.random()*10000000)/* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

}

In this case, How and when to get `notificationIntentBlahHello` from intent on MainActivity??

Comment: You'll get this intent after tap the notification in your MainActivity's onCreate method using getIntent() (in case if your activity was destroyed at the moment of tap the notification) or the intent will be in activity's onNewIntent() method in case if your activity is alive at the moment of tapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This intent:

```
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

Will go to or open your MainActivity.class. If you start your Activity this way, you can call the following in the onCreate() method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

Or you can override the onNewIntent() method:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    super.onNewIntent(intent); // Propagate or do something else with it
}
```